# Django - variable value, TypeError

Tags: python, django

I created a tag like this:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('post/comment_block.html')
def limit_amount_in_a_page(page_nr=1, post_id=1, amount=5):
    starting_index = page_nr*amount
    for index in range(starting_index, starting_index + amount):
        dosomething()
    has_prev = (page_nr != 0)
    has_next = ((page_nr + 1) * amount) < comments.count()

    return {
        something
    }
```

The problem is : page_nr is always not an int.

and this is how I call the tag and assign the value to page_nr in the tag:

```
{% limit_amount_in_a_page page_nr=my_page_nr post_id=post.id amount=4 %}
```

this is where the value of my_page_nr comes from:

```
def to_post_page(request, post_id, page_nr):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)
    form = CommentForm()
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(pk=post_id)
    return render(request, 'post/posts.html', {
        'post': post,
        'form': form,
        'comments': comments,
        'my_page_nr': page_nr,
    })
```

this is the url calling the view:

```
url(r'^(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<page_nr>[0-9]+)/$', views.to_post_page, name="post"),


{% for post in my_posts %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'forum:post' post.id 0 %} ">{{post.title}}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

The value passed to this url tag should be a int. As you can see, I passed a 0.
Really appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for `page_nr` is extracted from the URL, and is therefore a string. If you need it to be an int, it's simple to convert it - you could do this in the view, for example:

```
return render(request, 'post/posts.html', {
    'post': post,
    'form': form,
    'comments': comments,
    'my_page_nr': int(page_nr),
})
```

Comment: so any thing extracted from url will be a string, right? Thanks!